# Database Design: does it make sense to duplicate info in this case?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I'm building a service, kind of a social network, that is expected to attract trillions of users. Those users will be able to follow other users. For the case, let's imagine that I'm building Facebook. hah!

Next to each user's name, there will be the number of followers that he has. Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_vs_users 
  WHERE user_followed_id = 'xxx' GROUP BY user_followed;
```

would work, but doing that for each page reload and checking trillions of users would kill my server.

Is it reasonable to have a field named `num_of_followers` in the `users` table for each user, that is updated every time somebody is followed or unfollowed?

Thanks

Comment: What is this, a social network for ants?! (Assuming not for humans since we only number in the billions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Effectively, you are denormalising for performance reasons.

Comment: I accepted this answer because you introduced me to the concepto of "denormalization". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have another opinion here

Some databases can use memory (plus disk sync) like Oracle times ten and MySQL Cluster

Using memory based database only for data that is frequently accessed usually give great performance that simply make hassles of managing "counting" fields history

Another BIG tip, never optimise unless you have to, try to predict expected traffic for the next couple of months, not years, then you can monitor which queries actually are killing performance or doing too much disk access, just then you'll be able to de-normalize tables according to realistic information, not guesses

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, any self-respecting DBMS should internally perform such an optimization on its own accord. Or maybe they already do? Is COUNT(*) actually slow? I don't know.

Anyway, why not? Just make sure that "users_vs_users" and "users.num_of_followers" are synchronized at any time.